# Convert int values of an array into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following array

```
([[ 1,  1,  2,  2],
   [ 1,  1,  3,  3],
   [ 1,  1,  4,  4]])
```

I want to convert values from int to str, like this:

```
([[ '1',  '1',  '2',  '2'],
   [ '1',  '1',  '3',  '3'],
   [ '1',  '1',  '4',  '4']])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: When you say you have an `array`, are you referring to Python's `array.array` type or a `numpy.ndarray` type? Or - do you have a native Python list of lists?

Comment: array dtype=int64

Comment: So does `your_variable_name.astype(str)` do what you want then?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`arr` being your array with ints, you can do:

`list(map(lambda i: list(map(str,i)), arr))` with a one liner.

The result:

`[['1', '1', '2', '2'], ['1', '1', '3', '3'], ['1', '1', '4', '4']]`

Answer (score 0):

### The following might work:

```
def stringify_nested_containers(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, str):
        obj = list(obj)
        for idx in range(0, len(obj)):
            obj[idx] = stringify_nested_containers(obj[idx])
    else:
        obj = str(obj)
    return obj
```

### Example Usage:

```
lyst = [
            [ 1,  1,  2,  2],
            [ 1,  1,  3,  3],
            [ 1,  1,  4,  4]
]

slyst = stringify_nested_containers(lyst)
print(slyst)
print(type(slyst[0][0]))
```

### Warning:

For a string named `stryng`, `stryng[0]`, `stryng[539]`, or `stryng[whatever]` are not characters, they are strings.

Thus,

```
"h" == "hello world"[0]
```

and

```
"h" == "hello world"[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

Suppose you try to dig down into nested containers until you reach to an object which does not have an `__iter__` method (i.e. a non-container). Suppose there is a string in your nested container. Then you will end up in an infinite recursion or loop because `"a"[0]` is iterable for any character `"a"`. Specifically `"a"` has one element, `"a"[0]` and  `"a"[0]== "a"`.